# How to pass below html to below array of object format

Tags: arrays, object

Below is the html, we have to convert in array of object format :

see1, 
        v. 1. perceive, 
        look at, 
        behold,

```
    <span class="sn">2.</span> 
    <span class='word-item' data-id='620093'
    data-text='watch' data-syllables=''>perceive</span>, 
    <span class='word-item' data-id='620094' data-text='view'
    data-syllables=''>look at</span>, 
    <span class='word-item' data-id='620095' data-text='spectate'
    data-syllables=''><span class="ab">Sl.</span> behold</span>,
```

How to split this in below format :

```
"word":"see",
"list":
  [
    {
      "value":"1",
      "data":[
        {
        "data_id":"1",
          "data_text":"perceive"
        },
        {
        "data_id":"2",
          "data_text":"look at"
        },
        {
        "data_id":"3",
          "data_text":"behold"
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "value":"2",
      "data":[
        {
        "data_id":"1",
          "data_text":"perceive"
        },
        {
        "data_id":"2",
          "data_text":"look at"
        },
        {
        "data_id":"3",
          "data_text":"behold"
        }
      ]
    }
    
  
  ]
```

Response in below format :

"word":"see",
"list":
[
{
"value":"1",
"data":[
{
"data_id":"1",
"data_text":"perceive"
},
{
"data_id":"2",
"data_text":"look at"
},
{
"data_id":"3",
"data_text":"behold"
}
]
},
{
"value":"2",
"data":[
{
"data_id":"1",
"data_text":"perceive"
},
{
"data_id":"2",
"data_text":"look at"
},
{
"data_id":"3",
"data_text":"behold"
}
]
}

```
  ]
```